# DataGridViewCell with custom format fails to parse in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, format

I have a `DataGridView` with different columns. One of these columns holds a number (short) which represents a time. I have set the custom format to be `"00:00"` in the `cell style`. So if the number is 1800, the displayed (formatted) value is `18:00`, if the value is 50, the displayed value is 00:50.

This works perfectly fine as long as the cell's "`ParseFormattedValue`" method is not used. This method always fails with a format exception if I pass a formatted value like `"18:00"`, for example. Which doesn't this work even if the cell style's `Format-property` holds the correct format string?

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to method documentation:

```
    //   System.FormatException:
    //     The System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.FormattedValueType property value
    //     is null.-or-The System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.ValueType property
    //     value is null.-or-formattedValue cannot be converted.
```

Which parameters are you passing?

Comment: Both properties are not null. The FormattedValueType is "System.String", the ValueType is "System.Int16". I already knew that the formatted value could not be converted, this is what my question was all about ;-) I pass the FormattedValue of the cell, which is for example "18:00" and I pass the cell's Style property which has the format-string set.